# React is duplicating my object value giving me a Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, prop

Im trying to make a navigation bar for a website and it's giving me the "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." inside my *props.dropList.map*
I have two files:

- NavigationItems.js -> where I render my navigation bar

```
const NavigationItems = () => {
  const projectDropdown = [
    { id: 0, value: "architecture" },
    { id: 1, value: "land" },
    { id: 2, value: "design" },
    { id: 3, value: "list" },
  ];
  const officeDropdown = [
    { id: 4, value: "contact" },
    { id: 5, value: "team" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className={styles.NavigationItems}>
        <NavigationItem
          link={`/projects`}
          name="projects"
          dropList={projectDropdown}
        />
        <NavigationItem link={`/news`} name="news" exact />
        <NavigationItem
          link={`/office`}
          name="office"
          dropList={officeDropdown}
        />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavigationItems;
```

- NavigationItem.js -> where I use the map function

```
const NavigationItem = (props) => {
  let i = 0;
  return (
    <li className={styles.NavigationItem}>
      <NavLink to={props.link} activeClassName={styles.active}>
        {props.name}
      </NavLink>
      {props.dropList && (
        <div className={styles.DropdownItems}>
          <ul className={styles.DropdownItem}>
            {props.dropList.map((drop) => {
              console.log("i " + i);
              console.log("id " + drop.id);
              console.log("value " + drop.value);
              i++;
              return (
                <li key={drop.id}>
                  <NavLink
                    exact
                    to={`${props.link}/${drop.value}`}
                    activeClassName={styles.active}
                  >
                    {drop.value}
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

export default NavigationItem;
```

So what happens is that the code loops **twice** duplicating the key values. It should be looping only **once**. I don't know why it loops twice, I'm only mapping my values once. For reference
[this is what my console shows when I click my links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIdsM.png)

Comment: It doesnt loop twice, the NavigationItem Component is just rendered three times, so therfor it will console.log the ids three times. Could you provide some more info on the error, more specfically what comes after this `Check the render method of`

Comment: Oh i see. [Here is the error message](https://imgur.com/a/5GlqLn0)

Comment: You didnt add anything to ur comment

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to Stackoverflow. I edited my message

Comment: No problem. Also, if anything, also a comment is helpfull please upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem doesn't occure in either of the components you provided, but in your "Land" component. (Check the render method of Land)

Comment: Thank you. The problem was actually happening because I had some keys that were not defined correctly. I was already programming ahead of time and creating variables that still didn't exist